# Why can't I access the private variables of the superclass in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, private-members

I know that I *should* use the access methods.  I see in the `datetime` module that the class `datetime` inherits from date.

```
class datetime(date):
    <some other code here....>
    self = date.__new__(cls, year, month, day)
    self._hour = hour
    self._minute = minute
    self._second = second
    self._microsecond = microsecond
    self._tzinfo = tzinfo
    return self
```

I also see that datetime is able to access the members of date, as in `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    """Convert to formal string, for repr()."""
    L = [self._year, self._month, self._day, # These are never zero
         self._hour, self._minute, self._second, self._microsecond]
```

I tried to subclass datetime to add some information to it and then write a similar `__repr__` function:

```
def __repr__(self):
    """Convert to formal string, for repr()."""
    L = [self._year, self._month, self._day, # These are never zero
         self._hour, self._minute, self._second, self._microsecond,
         self._latitude, self._longitude]
```

The debugger complained that self._year didn't exist.  (`self.year` works, however.)

I know that I *should* be using the access function.  I just want to understand why `datetime` is able to access the private variables of `date` but my subclass isn't able.

Comment: Where did you see that Python code? In my Python distro (2.7.3), the `datetime` module is written in C and not in Python.

Comment: `class datetime(date):
    <some other code here....>
    self = date.__new__(cls, year, month, day)` o_O

Comment: I see the code in C:\Python32\Lib\datetime.py .  _year is in there as a member of date.  (I know that they are only private variables by convention.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the [end of `datetime.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1bee3da9a305/Lib/datetime.py#l2094), you'll see this:

```
try:
    from _datetime import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

this imports among other things the C-version of the previously defined python classes, which will therefore be used, and those don't have the members you're trying to access.

Comment: Indeed. You can't not access them because they are private, rather that they don't exist in the implementation he is using. This is why they are *indicated* as private - they are implementation details and not guaranteed to be there.

Comment: This also means that the OP can copy the Python classes and use them instead. And there might be a way to make that import fail (setting _datetime to None in sys.modules?) so that importing datetime gets you the Python version.

Comment: That also explains why my breakpoints in datetime.py aren't catching.  datetime.py isn't really being used, for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: @TryPyPy - Yes, sure that would be possible (tough a bit hacky), and as I understood it it's not a problem using the accessors as it's only about the representation - and understanding why the classes are different as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to subclass datetime to add some information to it

Don't do that. The combination of a datetime and latitude/longitude information is not logically a sub-type of datetime. It's a combination of two bits of data.

So create a class that has an attribute to store a datetime and an attribute to store latitude/longitude information (you might consider using a tuple of 2 numbers instead of having two separate values).